# What conversion is being used in these commands-- multiples of 16?

Tags: io

I'm controlling a board that has 16 outputs in two groups #1: 1-8, #2: 9-16.

The first part of the command is the group [1,...] or [2,...]

The second part is the output, so in the limited examples I am shown [1,1,...] would turn on [group 1, channel 1, ....]-- so far so good.

The next example is Output 8: [1, 128, ...]

The next example is Outputs 1 & 8: [1, 129, ...]

What is this conversion called?  I'm assuming the outputs map as follows, is this correct:

- Output 1 (or 9): 1
- Output 2 (or 10): 16
- Output 3 (or 11): 32
- ...
- Output 8 (or 16): 128

So if I wanted outputs 2 & 3 the command would be [1, 48]?

Comment: Can you Post the spec or datasheet

Comment: Yes, specifically looking at "Controlling the board w HMS Protocol" http://www.hms-electronics.com/BrightSign/data_sheets/usb-s3-16x16.htm

Comment: Looks like it has to be a doubling to get to 128 in 8 steps: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 ?

Answer (score 0):

You work with bits. 10000000 means turn on output 8. 10000000 in binary means 128 in decimal. If you wanted output 7 you’d do 1000000 which is 64 in decimal. Most programming languages would let you do something like 0x01001100 for example to turn on 7,4 and 3. Easier to work in binary.

Answer (score 0):

The generic formula for you to find the value to set 1 output would be:

```
second_part = 2^(output_to_set - 1)
```

For multiple outputs, you just need to add them.

So if you want to set, outputs 2 and 3:

```
second_part = 2^1 + 2^2 = 6
```

Comment: Great job on the answer. Don't forget to use _backticks_ on the code to make things more readable and take advantage of MD. Tx.